# Similar to beta regression for Generalized Additive Models and Generalized Linear Models

Tags: generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, beta-regression

My thesis is based on GAM and GLM. But my dependent variable is a proportion, meaning that $y \in (0,1)$ then I thought a better fit for this was the beta regression but this one is not considered in the GLM. What other distribution can I use for this dependent variable? I used the normal with the link function identity and log but I need another one to make a comparison.

Comment: Does it have to be a GLM *sensu stricto*? GLM-like algorithms are available for beta regression, for example in the *betareg* package for R. A GAM version is avialable in the *mgcv* package via family `betar`.

Comment: Yes, my thesis is a GLM vs GAM. But technically I can't use the beta uniparametric because is not with the exponential family.

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't have the sample total counts, that this is a true proportion? If so (true proportion) perhaps the quasi-binomial familyl, where you're just assuming a mean and variance relationship would be OK?

Comment: Actually my proportion is days a person took a medicine in a month, so technically is a count proportion.

Comment: Then you might model the data as binomial counts. You'll need to see how your software wants such data provided; R for example has several ways in which you can specify the sample totals or the positive (took a pill) and negative counts etc.